# Can I initialize public properties of a class using a different type in C#?

Tags: c#

In Java, I can have an object like this:

```
public class MyObject {

    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = parseDateString(date);
    }

    private Date parseDateString(String date) {
        // do magic here
        return dateObj;
    }

}
```

This is nice, because I have one getter for my properties, and multiple setters. I can set the "date" property by passing in either a Date object, or a String, and let the class figure it out.

In C# it looks like things are a little different. I can do this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

The shorthand here is obviously optimal. However, I'm not sure if there's any built-in way to overload the setter to accept multiple types. I realize I could create a separate public method to set the value, but that would sacrifice the ability to use object initializers.

Is there any way to directly overload the setter on public properties for C#? Or is this just a language limitation, and it can't be done?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would leave the string-to-date parsing outside the `MyClass`. In C# you just need to use `DateTime.Parse`, anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All other answers are correct... but **if you insist**, you can do it in several ways:

1. Use a second property with just a setter:

   ```
   public string DateText { set { Date = ParseDateString(value); } }
   ```

   Avoid this if possible, it only adds confusion :-)
2. Use methods instead of properties (same as you do in Java). Methods can be overloaded. This should be the most recommended way.
3. Use a custom class (instead of `DateTime`) and provide implicit conversions between `DateTime`, `string`, and your class. Not recommended unless you are going to use this everywhere else.
4. Change the property to `object` and provide your conversions in the setter: please don't do this

Comment: I'd bold-emphasis the **if you insist** part, set-only properties are a code smell in my books...+1 for completeness though ;)

Comment: Implicit conversions are very tricky when it comes to reading code. Instead you could use explicit conversions.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I don't recommend or endorse that way, but using explicit conversions kinda defies the purpose of "making it easy for the caller", since if you have to cast, you could aswell do the conversion (meaning: `ParseDateString("1/1/1900")` vs `(MyDate)"1/1/1900"` is not a lot of gain :-) )... but yes, I agree, and I'd personally avoid implicit conversions unless they are really necessary and *extremely* clear (which wouldn't be the case with a date/string).

Comment: @Jcl - I understand. I think the problem here is that the interpretation of "easy for the caller" is too vague in the original post. I just added the comment to prevent readers from thinking "Hey that is cool" and in the end getting bitten when trying to debug.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd 100% agreed

Answer (score 16):

Well, you're comparing apples to bananas. What you have in Java here:

```
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = parseDateString(date);
}
```

Would look like this in C#:

```
public void SetDate(Date date) 
{
    this.date = date;
}

public void SetDate(String date) 
{
    this.date = ParseDateString(date);
}
```

The only difference being the `PascalCase` member names and the location of the scope-opening brace.

Your Java code has overloaded *methods*; the above C# has overloaded methods.

AFAIK you can't overload a property setter, because:

```
public DateTime Date 
{ 
    get { return this.date; }
    set { this.date = value; }
}
```

...the type of `value` is determined by the type of the member, here `DateTime`.

So if you want method overloads, overload *methods*, not *properties*. Remember that C# properties are just syntax sugar for getter & setter methods anyway.

Comment: I don't think there's any conceptual reason why .NET couldn't have allowed properties to have overloaded setters, if .NET languages, upon seeing property-set syntax, would use the same overload logic as they would for a method (with the right-hand type of the expression as the first argument).  Semantically such a thing would be dodgy in cases where the result would be different from coercing the value to be set to the property's main type, but in cases where multiple types are mutually convertible, setting a prop directly to a particular type may be faster than converting and then setting.

Comment: @supercat I think it's more a language/syntax constraint (C#) than a .NET-wide thing. VB.NET does support parameterized getters/setters (heck, VB6 did!). Properties compile to `get_` and `set_` methods in CIL if I remember correctly.

Comment: In VB.NET and C#, property resolution occurs before the system determines what is being done with the property.  If it didn't, one could have an `IReadableFoo<out T>` interface which exposes a `Foo` property with a getter and `IWritableFoo<in T>` which exposes a `Foo` with a setter, and then have `IReadWriteFoo<T>` simply inherit both.  Because of the way binding is done, however, neither the getter nor setter will work on a variable of type `IReadWriteFoo<T>`; an attempt to say `it.Foo=9;` or `x=it.Foo;` will be rejected because it's (supposedly) ambiguous whether one is trying to use...

Comment: ...`IReadableFoo<T>.Foo` or `IWritableFoo<T>.Foo`.  I think it unfortunate that C# lacks parameterized indexers because there are cases where e.g. a generic version of `OrderedDictionary` could benefit from having a`foo.ByIndex[int]` and `foo.ByKey[TKey]` indexed properties without having to allow `var x=foo.ByIndex;`.

Comment: @supercat when you say "lacks parameterized indexers" - is that universally true? I can think of a few classes, particularly in the data namespace, where you can access eg a column collection either by its int position or string name - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index

Answer (score 10):

The auto properties do not support this. So you will have to do the same as you do in Java.

Of course you could mix these as well: provide an auto property and extra set-methods to set the property using different types.

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public void SetDate(string date) 
    {
        this.Date = DateTime.Parse(date);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to write a different answer and claim that

```
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = parseDateString(date);
}
```

is bad practice to begin with.

By doing the above, you are claiming that both strings and dates are valid values for `Date`.  This is not the case - what you really want is a `Date`.  If the user has a string and wants it converted a `Date`, they should be relying on the string-parsing functionality in the `Date` API *(`DateFormat.parse()` in Java, `DateTime.Parse()` in C#)*, not your API.

If `Date` is a class defined by you and you really do want `Date` and `string` to be interchangable, you should be using [implicit conversations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) in the `Date` class, not asking users of your `Date` class to write overloads.