# Overloading Property Setters

Tags: c#

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437796/can-i-initialize-public-properties-of-a-class-using-a-different-type-in-c), and it made me wonder.

Whenever I define a class with auto properties,

```
// Example A
public class MyObject
{
  public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

the JIT compiler will convert it to similar to this:

```
// Example B
public class MyObject
{
  private int _MyInt;

  public int get_MyInt()
  { 
    return _MyInt;
  }

  public void set_MyInt(int value)
  {
    _MyInt = value;
  }
}
```

So you could hypothetically write something like the following:

```
// Example C.1
public class MyObject 
{
  public int MyInt { get; set; }

  public void set_MyInt(string value)
  {
    MyInt = int.Parse(value);
  }
}
```

Or something potentially like this:

```
// Example C.2
public class MyObject 
{
  private int _myInt;
  public int MyInt 
  {
    get { return _myInt; }
    set 
    { 
      _myInt = value; 
    }
    set(string) 
    { 
      _myInt = int.Parse(value); 
    }
  }
}
```

And have this functionality exist without compiler errors.

```
// Example D
public void DoSomething(string someIntegerAsAString)
{
  var myObject = new MyObject()
  {
    MyInt = someIntegerAsAString
  };
}
```

What's stopping the compiler from saying code such as **Example D**, where the desired result is inferred and it works correctly and expected? The functionality is there, shown in **Example B**.

Is this something that's against how the language designers have designed the language to work and behave?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you in the first example. Compilation errors are stopping you in the second. Overloaded property setters are not supported. You might as well just use a method. There's probably some exotic ways to abuse it as well so why waste time, effort and money on something very rarely used?

Comment: In fact you can do method overload with dynamic bindings http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsC4MethodOverloadingAndDynamicTypes.aspx, not possible with auto-IMPLEMENTED property but it can help sometimes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading properties in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608892/overloading-properties-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

You can, indeed, do this...

```
public class MyObject 
{
  public int MyInt { get; set; }

  public void set_MyInt(string value)
  {
    MyInt = int.Parse(value);
  }
}
```

...inspite of the obvious performance overhead of converting a string to an int.

This will not work:

```
public class MyObject 
{
  private int _myInt;
  public int MyInt 
  {
    get { return _myInt; }
    set 
    { 
      _myInt = value; 
    }
    set(string) 
    { 
      _myInt = int.Parse(value); 
    }
  }
}
```

...because C# doesn't support `setter` overload. However, you could achieve something kind of similar with [implicit type conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx), but it has to be implemented on your own types. Integer is a value type so it's inherently sealed.

Comment: I realize this. But the *key* that I'm talking about is that the compiler recognizing this functionality. I guess I'm wanting more information (at a high level) of why the compiler doesn't support something like this where, from my perspective, the basic framework for the functionality exists.

Comment: @Cameron: I realise I am very late to the party, but as a regular reader of Eric Lippert's blog (who used to work on the C# compiler) I think the likeliest explanation why the C# compiler does not allow overloaded setters is this: It simply wasn't perceived as a useful or important enough language feature. As Eric always pointed out, implementing a feature has a cost, so unless a feature isn't wanted badly enough, it won't be there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `JIT` that generates the `get_*` and `set_*` methods for the properties.

If you decompile this code:

```
public int MyInt { get; set; }
```

you'll get this IL:

```
.property instance int32 MyInt()
{
    .get instance int32 C::get_MyInt()
    .set instance void C::set_MyInt(int32)
} // end of property C::MyInt

.method public hidebysig specialname instance int32 
        get_MyInt() cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
    // Code size       11 (0xb)
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init (int32 V_0)
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldfld      int32 C::'<MyInt>k__BackingField'
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
    IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009
    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method C::get_MyInt

.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_MyInt(int32 'value') cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
    // Code size       8 (0x8)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldarg.1
    IL_0002:  stfld      int32 C::'<MyInt>k__BackingField'
    IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method C::set_MyInt
```

If you look at [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx), you'll see that it has a [GetMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod.aspx) and a [SetMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ibrary/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod.aspx). "Method", not "Methods".

This is tied to the framework, although I don't know any language where a property has more than one getter or setter. Do you know any such language?

Comment: LinqPad shows a simplified view of IL. I think the output of ildasm would be more helpful here.

Comment: Because it would show the `.property` and that you set the getter and setter there.

Comment: @svick D is such a language. A setter there is a method with one parameter. As with methods, you can have multiple with different types.

Comment: Since they are just methods than it's probably not terribly difficult to overload them if the .net team decided that was important to put on the roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

The C# designers did give us the ability to implement implicit type conversion. However, they probably didn't want that to work with the primitive types to avoid confusion.

Imagine this lines:

```
var myvar = 2;
myvar = "4";
```

Anyone looking at the above lines would think we're talking about a dynamic language like JavaScript. In JavaScript, `myvar` would be a string from the second line on. If C# supported what you described, it would still be an `int`. I, for one, would find it confusing.